# Refresh div and table without time interval when event occur

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am using a table in a div, table contains edit and delete functionality of that record. when i delete that record, fresh data has to fill in table, how can i do this by ajax and jquery.
Any Suggestions plz..

Thanks In advance

Comment: What have you already tried and what do you currently have?

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

you should add onclick eventhandler to that div delete button. In the function that handles that event you should make Ajax request to some "BlackBox" which will return as a result JSON with a 'Fresh data', which you will use in JavaScript to fill your table. As a "BlackBox" it can be some web-service, MVC controller action(which will return not view but JSON) or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the [jQuery dataTable](http://datatables.net/index) for a better layout and a huge amount of possibilities.

And while you are using .Net, I strongly suggest you to use MVC pattern.